# R - Violin plots with many columns

Tags: r, math, graph, plot

I am trying to plot a violin plot with many columns. I will be reading in a file like so:

```
data <- read.table("file.txt", as.is=TRUE);
```

The data file will have many rows, each of which should be a column. The problem is that I don't know beforehand how many rows the data file will have. From what I've found through research, I can make a violin plot like so:

```
vioplot(x, y, z, ....);
```

which would give me just a preset number of columns. How would I go about handling all of the rows? Also, I'd have a list of strings that would correspond with the columns, so the naming parameter would also require a similar approach.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Umm.. but after you have read in the data using `read.table`, don't you have access to the number of rows and columns using `nrow` and `ncol`?

Comment: The issue is that I need to be able to dynamically have x number of columns for the violin plot. I don't know how to make that happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
set.seed(101)
write.table(matrix(runif(1000),nrow=10),file="tmpfile.txt")
##
```

Basically, you want to transpose your data and turn them into a list of columns ...

```
dat <- read.table("tmpfile.txt", as.is=TRUE)
cdat <- as.list(as.data.frame(t(as.matrix(dat))))
names(cdat)[1] <- "x"  ## vioplot() needs the first element to be called 'x'
library(vioplot)
```

Then use `do.call`

```
do.call(vioplot,cdat)
```

If you have a vector of names you want to use:

```
do.call(vioplot,c(cdat,list(names=nameVector)))
```

(other arguments would get added to the additional-arguments list along with `names`)

In the long run, I would recommend (1) storing your data columnwise rather than rowwise, if possible; and (2) getting acquainted with `geom_violin()` in `ggplot2` -- it's much more flexible.

```
library(reshape2)
mdat <- melt(t(as.matrix(dat)))  ## convert to long format
```

Now the data are stored as a 100 row by 3 column data frame with variables `Var1` 
(which indicates the column from the original data set) and `Var2` (the row 
from the original data set, which corresponds to one of the variables).

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mdat,aes(x=factor(Var2),y=value))+geom_violin()+
   labs(x="variable")
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! Say I have another table with names for each plot, how would I go about setting the name for each violin plot?

Comment: via `vioplot` or `ggplot2`?  Do you have the table read into R already? (If not I suggest `scan(...,what="character")`)

Comment: Using vioplot. Yes, I have a table ready. I tried something like do.call(vioplot,cdat, names=c("one", "two")); but did not have any luck. How would a table that is read in work?

Comment: Ah.  It would be `do.call(vioplot,c(cdat,list(names=nameVector)))` (**not** obvious!)

Comment: I don't find the last example with ggplot helpful. What is Var2, what is value? I would like it to plot violins for all columns, just like in your example with vioplot (i don't like vioplot's look).

Answer (score 5):

`do.call` is the idiom required.

eg

```
nd <- data.frame(t(data))
```

Now, `vioplot` requires an argument to be named `x` (the rest get passed in `...`))

```
# have the first column called `x`
names(nd)[1] <- 'x'


 do.call('vioplot', nd)
```

Comment: +1 I didn't check beforehand but I thought about this but thought it would plot separate plots for each column so went with what I posted. I didn't realise `do.call` would construct all vioplots on the same plot window. Cool.

Answer (score 2):

How about using `parse` and `eval` to dynamically build and evaluate an expression (probably not a good way, but I think it will fit your needs)....

```
#  Turn rows into columns
nd <- t(data)

#  Explicitly give some names to your columns
colnames(nd) <- paste0( "V",1:ncol(nd) )

#  Make some violin plots
require(vioplot)
eval( parse( text = paste0( "vioplot(" , paste0( paste0( "nd[,\"" , colnames(nd) , "\"]" ) , collapse="," , sep="" ) , ")" ) ) )
```